# Call a Wordpress shortcode with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a shortcode in Wordpress which I want to call it with jQuery with the click of a button. I read a few websites and tutorials, but I cannot figure exactly what happen.

I put this on function.php:

```
add_action( 'init', function() { 
  ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'ps_get_survey_form', 'ps_get_survey_form' ); 
} );

function ps_register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {

  if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != $action )
    return;

  call_user_func( $callable );
}

function ps_get_survey_form() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[dopbsp id=6 lang=el]' );
    die(); 
}
```

And this on the page-template.php I use:

```
<button id="testonclick" onclick="test()"></button>

<div id="testresults"></div>

<script>

function test() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/myweb" + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data : {action: 'ps_get_survey_form'},
        success: function(results){
            jQuery("#testresults").html(results)
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){console.log(errorThrown);}
    });// end of ajax
}
</script>
```

However, the results is 0. Any idea what happened wrong?

Comment: Not tested it but the ```die();``` inside ```ps_get_survey_form``` function will almost certainly be causing you an issue.

Comment: I tried to remove it and I have the same 0. :(

Comment: Can you use the heartbeat api?

Comment: I think yes. I haven't used it before, so I don't know how. I have access and I can install any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to be using something like

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ps_get_survey_form', 'ps_get_survey_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ps_get_survey_form', 'ps_get_survey_form' );
```

instead of your

```
add_action( 'init', function() { ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'ps_get_survey_form', 'ps_get_survey_form' ); } );
```

You can read more about that on [this Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)).

As far as I know, what you wrote doesn't make your function available via AJAX at all. I certainly don't know everything though. This is just the method that I use.

Answer (score 0):

You should look over this article on WP and AJAX.  It is best to 'tie' the ajax call to the admin ajax script.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

```
add_action("wp_ajax_my_user_vote", "my_user_vote");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_user_vote", "my_must_login");
```

and

```
 wp_register_script( "my_voter_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my_plugin/my_voter_script.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

be aware though that the shortcode may load css or js that is needed for the form, which won't get loaded via the ajax call.